# Why does this error appear? "TypeError: mkdirp is not a function"

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

The above error occurred when I was running the code, so the process of creating the file is not working. Please let me know the solution.

This code is used to calculate the results based on the Naver Trend API and Naver Advertising API, and then create a graph. It is written in two files, server and addon, and the keys are created in another file and sent. The entire code seems to be fine, but it seems that the module is not installed properly or the file path is wrong. I've been looking for a solution, but I can't find it.

```
const request = require("request-promise");
const crypto = require("crypto");
const axios = require("axios");
const vega = require("vega");
const fs = require("fs");
const mkdirp = require("mkdirp");
const path = require("path");

const account = require("./account");
const spec = require("./default_chart_spec.json");

async function getClickRatios(keyword, date, device = "", gender = "") {
  console.log("device : ", device);
  let request_body = {
    startDate: date[0],
    endDate: date[1],
    timeUnit: "month",
    keywordGroups: [
      {
        groupName: "KW",
        keywords: [keyword],
      },
    ],
    device: device,
    gender: gender,
  };

  client_id = "";
  client_secret = "";

  let option = {
    method: "POST",
    uri: "https://openapi.naver.com/v1/datalab/search",
    body: JSON.stringify(request_body),
    headers: {
      "X-Naver-Client-Id": client_id,
      "X-Naver-Client-Secret": client_secret,
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  };
  let msg = await request(option);
  let json = JSON.parse(msg);
  return json;
}

async function getClickCnt(keyword, date) {
  //코드는 getClickCnt라는 비동기 함수를 정의
  client_id = "4jc3nDuSjniu9JXDkdbm";
  client_secret = "Fk05DUQBH7";

  const path = "/keywordstool";
  const timestamp = new Date().getTime();
  const msg = `${timestamp}.GET.${path}`;
  const signature = crypto
    .createHmac("SHA256", account.secretKey)
    .update(msg)
    .digest("base64");
  //const formatted = keywords.map(e => e.keyword).join(',')
  const option = {
    method: "get",
    url: `https://api.searchad.naver.com${path}`,
    params: {
      format: "json",
      hintKeywords: keyword,
    },
    headers: {
      "X-Timestamp": timestamp,
      "X-Customer": account.customerId,
      "X-API-KEY": account.accessLicense,
      "X-Signature": signature,
    },
  };

  //let data = await request(option);
  return await axios(option);
}
//이 함수를 호출하면 지정된 키워드와 기간에 대한 클릭 수 데이터가 반환

function pad(n, width) {
  n = n + "";
  return n.length >= width ? n : new Array(width - n.length + 1).join("0") + n;
}
// pad 함수는 숫자 형식을 특정 너비로 패딩
function getDir(keyword, date, target) {
  if (target === "directory_file") return path.join("chart_image", keyword);
  if (target === "image_file")
    return path.join("chart_image", keyword, date[2] + ".png");
}
//getDir 함수는 특정 목적에 따라 경로를 생성

//================================================================================

module.exports = {
  async getClickRatios(keyword, date, device = "", gender = "") {
    console.log("device : ", device);
    let request_body = {
      startDate: date[0],
      endDate: date[1],
      timeUnit: "month",
      keywordGroups: [
        {
          groupName: "KW",
          keywords: [keyword],
        },
      ],
      device: device,
      gender: gender,
    };

    client_id = "";
    client_secret = "";

    let option = {
      method: "POST",
      uri: "https://openapi.naver.com/v1/datalab/search",
      body: JSON.stringify(request_body),
      headers: {
        "X-Naver-Client-Id": client_id,
        "X-Naver-Client-Secret": client_secret,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    };
    let msg = await request(option);
    let json = JSON.parse(msg);
    return json;
  },

  async getClickCnt(keyword, date) {
    client_id = "";
    client_secret = "";

    const path = "/keywordstool";
    const timestamp = new Date().getTime();
    const msg = `${timestamp}.GET.${path}`;
    const signature = crypto
      .createHmac("SHA256", account.secretKey)
      .update(msg)
      .digest("base64");
    //const formatted = keywords.map(e => e.keyword).join(',')
    const option = {
      method: "get",
      url: `https://api.searchad.naver.com${path}`,
      params: {
        format: "json",
        hintKeywords: keyword,
      },
      headers: {
        "X-Timestamp": timestamp,
        "X-Customer": account.customerId,
        "X-API-KEY": account.accessLicense,
        "X-Signature": signature,
      },
    };

    //let data = await request(option);
    return await axios(option);
  },

  async getTrend(keyword, date) {
    let click_ratio_json = await getClickRatios(keyword, date);
    let info = await getClickCnt(keyword, date);
    let data = info.data.keywordList[0];
    click_info = [data.monthlyPcQcCnt, data.monthlyMobileQcCnt];
    click_info[0] = click_info[0] == "< 10" ? 0 : click_info[0];
    click_info[1] = click_info[1] == "< 10" ? 0 : click_info[1];
    click_total = click_info[0] + click_info[1];

    console.log("click_ratio : ", click_ratio_json.results[0].data);
    console.log("click totla : ", click_total);

    let click_per_ratio =
      click_total / int(click_ratio_json.results[0].data[12]["ratio"]);

    let click_trend = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++)
      click_trend.push(
        Math.ceil(
          click_ratio_json.results[0].data[i]["ratio"] * click_per_ratio
        )
      );

    return click_trend;
  },

  async getTrendp(keyword, date, device) {
    let click_ratio_json;
    if (device === "total")
      click_ratio_json = await getClickRatios(keyword, date);
    else if (device === "pc")
      click_ratio_json = await getClickRatios(keyword, date, "pc");
    else if (device === "mobile")
      click_ratio_json = await getClickRatios(keyword, date, "mo");

    console.log("fin");
    let info = await getClickCnt(keyword, date);
    let data = info.data.keywordList[0];
    click_info = [data.monthlyPcQcCnt, data.monthlyMobileQcCnt];
    click_info[0] = click_info[0] == "< 10" ? 0 : click_info[0];
    click_info[1] = click_info[1] == "< 10" ? 0 : click_info[1];

    console.log("click info : ", click_info);
    if (device === "total") click_total = click_info[0] + click_info[1];
    else if (device == "pc") click_total = click_info[0];
    else if (device == "mobile") click_total = click_info[1];

    console.log("click_ratio : ", device, click_ratio_json.results[0].data);
    console.log("click_total : ", device, click_total);

    let click_per_ratio =
      click_total / click_ratio_json.results[0].data[11]["ratio"];
    console.log("click_per_ratio : ", click_per_ratio);
    let click_trend = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++)
      click_trend.push(
        Math.ceil(
          click_ratio_json.results[0].data[i]["ratio"] * click_per_ratio
        )
      );

    console.log("=========================");
    return click_trend;
  },

  async veg2png(keyword, date) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      let view = new vega.View(vega.parse(spec), {
        renderer: "none",
      }).initialize();
      view
        .toCanvas()
        .then(function (canvas) {
          console.log("Writing PNG to file...");
          const directory_file_dir = getDir(
            keyword,
            date,
            (target = "directory_file")
          );
          const image_file_dir = getDir(keyword, date, (target = "image_file"));
          mkdirp(directory_file_dir, (err) => {
            fs.writeFileSync(image_file_dir, canvas.toBuffer());
            resolve();
          });
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
          console.log("Error writing PNG to file:");
          console.error(err);
        });
    });
  },

  getDate(term = "1y") {
    let today = new Date();
    let before = new Date();

    before.setYear(today.getFullYear() - 1);
    let today_f =
      today.getFullYear() +
      "-" +
      pad(today.getMonth() + 1, 2) +
      "-" +
      pad(today.getDate(), 2);
    let before_f =
      before.getFullYear() +
      "-" +
      pad(before.getMonth() + 1, 2) +
      "-" +
      pad(before.getDate(), 2);

    let today2_f =
      today.getFullYear() + "-" + pad(today.getMonth() + 1, 2) + "-" + "01";
    return [before_f, today_f, today2_f];
  },

  getDir(keyword, date, target) {
    if (target === "directory_file") return path.join("chart_image", keyword);
    if (target === "image_file")
      return path.join("chart_image", keyword, date[2] + ".png");
  },

  setChart(trends) {
    console.log("setting Charing!");
    spec.data[0].values = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
      // if dic (pc and mobile and all)
      for (let j = 0; j < trends.length; j++) {
        let graph_data = { x: i, y: trends[j][i], c: j };
        spec.data[0].values.push(graph_data);
      }
    }
    console.log("spec value : ", spec.data[0].values);
    fs.writeFileSync("./default_chart.spec.json", JSON.stringify(spec));
    console.log("write complie!!");
  },
};
```

I deleted the secret key

```
const request = require("request-promise");
const express = require("express");
const fs = require("fs");
const asyncify = require("express-asyncify");
const app = asyncify(express());
const path = require("path");
const Addon = require("./Addon");
const port = 59239;

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

app.get("/keytool", async (req, res) => {
  keyword = req.query.kw;
  //let trend = Addon.getTrendp(keyword, date);
  let date = Addon.getDate(); // [before, today, today(날짜가 1)];
  console.log(date);
  let dir = Addon.getDir(keyword, date, (target = "image_file"));
  let exists = fs.existsSync(dir);
  if (!exists) {
    // if file is not exist
    console.log("making graph!!");
    let trend_pc = await Addon.getTrendp(keyword, date, (device = "pc"));
    let trend_mobile = await Addon.getTrendp(
      keyword,
      date,
      (device = "mobile")
    );
    let trend_all = await Addon.getTrendp(keyword, date, (device = "total"));
    let trends = [trend_pc, trend_mobile, trend_all];
    console.log("trends : ", trends);
    Addon.setChart(trends);
    Addon.veg2png(keyword, date).then(function () {
      console.log("after veg2png");

      //Addon.setChart(trend_all);
      fs.readFile(dir, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
          res.status(404).end();
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          res.set("Content-Type", "image/png");
          console.log("img data : ", data);
          res.send(data);
        }
      });
    });
  } else {
    //file is exist
    console.log("graph already exist!!");
    fs.readFile(dir, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        res.status(404).end();
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        res.set("Content-Type", "image/png");
        console.log(data);
        res.send(data);
      }
    });
  }
});

let server = app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log("Server is Running at http://localhost:59239/keytool?kw=");
});
```

I ran this code on my local server, but the subsequent tasks were not completed after the output of the result.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [the documentation](https://github.com/isaacs/node-mkdirp):

> ```
> // hybrid module, import or require() both work
> import { mkdirp } from 'mkdirp'
> // or:
> const { mkdirp } = require('mkdirp')
> ```

The export is an **object**. The `mkdirp` function is a property of that object.

You are trying to call the object itself as if it were a function.